# How to understand this doc

Tags: python, slot

This is from [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots). I don't understand this, can someone give some examples?

> If a class defines a slot also defined in a base class, the instance
>   variable defined by the base class slot is inaccessible (except by
>   retrieving its descriptor directly from the base class). This renders
>   the meaning of the program undefined. In the future, a check may be
>   added to prevent this.

I tried to make an example of this but failed. When I run the program below it prints `1`, so the variable is not inaccessible. When would it be?

```
class Base(object):
    __slots__ = 'a'

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

class Subclass(Base):
    __slots__ = 'a'

    def __init__(self):
        super(Subclass, self).__init__()
        print self.a

Subclass()
```

Comment: Excerpt is fairly straight-forward. Exactly what part of it you do not understand?

Comment: I tried putting together an example to answer your question and discovered the opposite of what the docs said, so I edited it into your question and now I'm also interested to see what answers people have.

Comment: the instance variable defined by the base class slot is inaccessible，b = Base()
print b.a          I thought the b.a is inaccessible,what the inaccessible is?

Answer (score 2):

> When I run the program below it prints 1, so the variable is not inaccessible.

You actually have *two* `a` instance variables here. The one defined by `Base` is not accessible through attribute access; for an object of type `Subclass`, all accesses to `self.a`, including the one inside `Base.__init__`, go to the instance variable defined by `Subclass`.

If you retrieve the `Base.a` descriptor manually, you can access the slot defined by `Base`:

```
>>> x = Subclass()
1
>>> Base.a.__get__(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: a
>>> Base.a.__set__(x, 2)
>>> Base.a.__get__(x)
2
>>> Subclass.a.__get__(x)
1
```

As you can see, `Base.a` and `Subclass.a` are independent, despite sharing the same name.

Comment: If subclass does not have __slots__,  x = Subclass(); Base.a.__get__(x) will work, the doc mean this? I always thought is b = Base() ; then b.a is not accessable!!